# WatchKit Menu Items Not Displaying

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I'm in Xcode 6.2 Beta 3 (Build 6C101), I've added a menu and two menu items to my Interface Controller, and created IBActions for both. I've given them titles and images, but when I run the app nothing displays.

I've read

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Menus.html

and can't see anything about need to show menu items programatically - what am I missing?

Comment: Did you add customs images ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not need to present the menu programmatically. The only thing you need to do is wire each button to IBActions in your Watch app extension.

The most likely issue is caching of the previous Watch app storyboard. Do a clean build and try again.

Finally, as you likely know WatchKit menus only display on a "force press". They cannot be used for the main interface of the Watch app. In the Simulator, a click and hold with the mouse will simulate a force press, and the animation will make it clear when you have done one, even in contexts where it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Force Press was the issue - thanks very much Duncan!

Comment: I still have problems. First it only showed the first item. After deleting it it shows no item now, even if there are 2 more in the menu. "Product -> Clean" didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This was solution for me- Go to Hardware->Touch Pressure->Deep Press then try tap on watch simulator.

Comment: To Add to this, the shortcuts are CMD+SHIFT+1 for shallow press and CMD+SHIFT+2 for deep press. Then use your mouse to click on the watch and simulate the selected press.

Comment: What's more, if ur MacBook contains a touch bar, u'll see a touch pressure button there, by pressing it will toggle between "shallow press" & "deep press".

Answer (score 0):

I have recently encountered this issue on a real device, although the menu was working as expected on the watch simulator. In my case, the problem was in SF Symbol that I've used as an image.

Everything was fixed after replacing it with an image from the assets catalogue.